# How can I show an ampersand in XAML text string?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add an ampersand like this:

```
<Label Text="Phrase & Meaning Visible" />
```

This doesn't work so I tried to delimit with a \ and that also does not work.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: This doc specifies it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-special-characters-in-xaml

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually this question is not about XAML, it's just a pure XML question. Some characters need to be escaped in XML, the correct escaping of `&` is `&amp;`

Comment: Oh really! Can you share a resource where I can learn more about this.

Comment: Sure :) https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp -> Entity References

Answer (score 8):

Taken this with thanks from the following blog post.
[Special Symbols in XAML](https://www.includehelp.com/xamarin/use-special-symbols-in-label-as-text.aspx)

> ```
> For Ampersand sign <Label Text="&amp;"/>
> For less than sign <Label Text="&lt;">
> For greater than sign <Label Text="&gt;"/>
> For double quotes <Label Text="&quot;"/>
> ```